# Reverse Portrait For Android

Tags: android, layout, rotation, touch, screen

I want to reverse the orientation of my device.
I tried using the option ro.sf.hwrotation 180 but it rotates the display but doesn't rotate the touch.

I have found many leads through patches but all are for froyo or Gingerbread. I need it for JellyBean(4.1.2).

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

"reversePortrait"   Portrait orientation in the opposite direction from normal portrait. Added in API level 9.

Comment: hello veon
I was not able to understand what exactly you were trying to tell, API level 9 is 2.3.3 i know that, but i did find some patches to reverse the orientation for Froyo but presently the device which I am exploring is based on 4.2.1 and I would like any help possible to  reverse the orientation of the device which includes the display as well as the touch.